# Control is null when used nested master pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I have a simple hierarchy of nested master pages.
However, in runtime, the master page controls (exemplified by label1) are always null.

If `Default.aspx` is changed to use `Base.master` directly, the master page controls will be correctly defined.

What is the cause for this behavior?

---

**Base.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" CodeFile="Base.master.cs" Inherits="BaseMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server"></head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="label1" Text="Label 1" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Base.master.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class BaseMaster : MasterPage
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        label1.Text = "Base"; // Causes NullReferenceException
    }
}
```

---

**Sub.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" CodeFile="Sub.master.cs" Inherits="SubMaster" MasterPageFile="~/Base.master" CodeFileBaseClass="BaseMaster" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="SubMainContent" />
</asp:Content>
```

**Sub.master.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class SubMaster : BaseMaster
{
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        label1.Text = "Sub"; // Causes NullReferenceException
    }
}
```

---

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DefaultPage" MasterPageFile="~/Sub.master" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="SubMainContent">
    <h3>Default</h3>
</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class DefaultPage : Page
{
}
```

Comment: I don't see how `Base.master.cs` would throw a null ref eception on the line you indicate, and I don't see how `Sub.master.cs` would compile because there is no label1 control. Are you sure you are getting the error on an up to date build.

Comment: When coding, the IntelliSense shows label1 in boths master-pages. Editor hints 'Label BaseMaster.label1' too. I can build the Web Site Application. Running, the `BaseMaster` throws the exception. Comment the line, then `SubMaster` throws the exception.

Comment: I found a clue: the class `BaseMaster` has the attribute label1 correctly. There is a generated class `base_master`, who extends `BaseMaster` and include a method called in `FrameworkInitialize` to build label1.

Comment: At the same time, the class 'SubMaster' extends `BaseMaster`, again correctly. But this generated a class `sub_master`, who extends `SubMaster` but not `base_master`. Then, I have a definition to label1, but the method to build it is not defined. There must be a way to force ASP.net generate the code to build label1.